# php explode help

Tags: php, explode

I have this data set from a textarea

```
P234324, 2011-03-23 12:34:37 \nP234434, 2011-03-23 13:34:36 \nP438794, 2011-03-23 14:34:36 \nP238924, 2011-03-23 15:34:36 \n
```

I would like to explode it to this, but the multiple foreach is throwing me.

```
$data['P234324'] = "2011-03-23 12:34:37"
$data['P234434'] = "2011-03-23 13:34:36"
$data['P438794'] = "2011-03-23 14:34:36"
$data['P238924'] = "2011-03-23 15:34:36"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$old_data = ...; //your string
$data = array();

$pairs = explode("\n", rtrim($old_data, "\n"));
foreach($pairs as $pair) {
   $components = explode(',', $pair);
   $data[$components[0]] = trim($components[1]);
}
```

**[codepad example](http://codepad.org/IZ5M8R5J)**